# Grails encoded params Post Request

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am trying to complete the Instagram Oauth flow,

I currently have the authorization code which I'm to exchange for the access token. I am to make an  x-www-form-urlencoded POST request to this endpoint

"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?"

This is what I've done so far.

```java
String query = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/?client_id=" + clientId +"&client_secret="+ clientSecret+ "&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri="+ redirectUri + "&code=" + code

String response = new URL(query).getText()
```

A JSON string is expected as response.

Please Keep in mind that I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the Instagram documentation but based on your example code there's a couple of things to keep in mind:

- you mentioned that you have to make a POST request, your example makes a GET request
- never build a URL with untrusted parameter values. This basically means: **always** encode parameters, never trust them.

There are dozens of 3rd party HTTP Request libraries that give you flexibility and easier insight into aspects like timeouts and redirects. Java 11 has a built-in HTTP client that might ease this as well. But building on your code provided in your question using basic Java connection primitives this might work:

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/?client_id=${URLEncoder.encode(clientId, 'UTF-8')}&client_secret=${URLEncoder.encode(clientSecret, 'UTF-8')}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=${URLEncoder.encode(redirectUri, 'UTF-8')}&code=${URLEncoder.encode(code, 'UTF-8')}")
def jsonString = ((HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()).with {
    setRequestMethod('POST')
    setRequestProperty('Accept', 'application/json')
    setDoInput(true)
    connect()

    if (getResponseCode() >= 400)
        throw new Exception("Error code = ${getResponseCode()}")

    inputStream.text
}
```

Every URL parameter is encoded so that any non-URL safe characters they contain are made safe, then we tell the connection that it will be a 'POST' and that we expect to get back json as input. `inputStream.text` is groovy code that takes an inputstream from the connection and reads all of the contents and then closes the stream. Since it is the last line of the `with` closure it is automatically returned as the value of the closure and assigned to the variable `jsonString`.